# Angular 4 + Firebase getting the value out of a snapshot when requesting database

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm trying to get items out of a Firebase DB, but it looks I can't.
The operator "this" is not working in the snapshot function (on the line `this.authState.prenom = snapshot.val().prenom`)

And If I do it outside the function, it seems it's executed before the function, so the attribute is empty. The only solution I found is to put a timeout (one the line `setTimeout( () => this.authState.prenom = prenom,1000)"` but it's not what I want.

I just want the declaration `this.authState.prenom = prenom;` executed after the snapshot function is over or getting the value out of this snapshot function in any way.

Here is my file (variables are all declared)

**auth.service.ts**
Here is the constructor :

```
  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  private db: AngularFireDatabase,
  private router:Router) {

this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((auth) => {
  this.authState = auth;

  if(this.currentUser){
    var userId = this.currentUser.uid;

    var prenom: any;
    var nom: any;

    firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).on('value',function(snapshot) {
      // this.authState.prenom = snapshot.val().prenom; <= This is not working because I can't use "this" operator here and don't know why

      console.log(snapshot.val().prenom);
      console.log(snapshot.val().nom);

      prenom = snapshot.val().prenom;
      nom = snapshot.val().nom;

      // this.authState.nom = snapshot.val().nom; <= not working because of the operator "this"
    });
    this.authState.prenom = prenom // <= Not working because it's executed before the snapshot function and don't know why
    setTimeout( () => this.authState.prenom = prenom,1000); // <= This is working but setting timeout is not a good thing..
    setTimeout( () => this.authState.nom = nom,1000);
    // console.log(this.authState.prenom);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the `this` working, use fat arrow function notation (as you do with the `auth.subscribe`):

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).on('value', (snapshot) => {
  this.authState.prenom = snapshot.val().prenom;
  this.authState.nom = snapshot.val().nom;
});
```

Some more old-school alternatives:

```
var that = this; // capture the correct this in a variable
firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).on('value', function(snapshot) {
  that.authState.prenom = snapshot.val().prenom;
  that.authState.nom = snapshot.val().nom;
});
```

Or:

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).on('value', function(snapshot) {
  this.authState.prenom = snapshot.val().prenom;
  this.authState.nom = snapshot.val().nom;
}, this); // pass in the this as the last parameter
```

For more information, I highly recommend reading [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! The fat arrow function worked perfectly for me :)